# While trying to delete a row via postman i get this Error Message id is not defined

Tags: node.js

I am using Nodejs as my back end, I have created a simple CRUD application but I am getting a problem when i try to delete a row via my postman API. Please any one who can help me to fix this. Thanks

here is my controller code for delete method

```
exports.deleteProfile=(req, res) =>{
  models.Profile.destroy({
      where: {
        id: id
      }
    }).then(response=>{
      console.log(response)
      res.status(200).json({
        message:'Profile deleted'
      })
    })

    }
```

and this is my delete route

```
router.delete( '/:id', PostController.deleteProfile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
where: {
        id: id
      }
```

TO

```
where: {
        id: req.params.id
      }
```